# How does your main thread's serial queue divide up its code? (iOS/Objective-C)

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch

To clarify what I mean, let's say we have some code as instance methods for some object, let's say a view controller:

```
- (void)foo {
    //do foo stuff A
    [self bar];
    //do foo stuff B
}
- (void)bar {
    //do bar stuff
}
```

We call this code inside a view controller's viewDidLoad or something:

```
[self foo]
```

Does the code go into the main queue as a series of blocks, in which the first block contains

```
//do foo stuff A
```

the second block contains

```
//do bar stuff
```

and the third block contains

```
//do foo stuff B
```

Or does it work differently?

Edit: Based on people telling me this is confusing because my code has nothing to do with GCD, let me clarify what caused me to wonder about this in the first place.

We know that

```
- (void)foo {
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

will cause the program to deadlock because dispatch_sync block is stuck on the queue forever (or is this not true?). Now this is the part I'm unclear on: What does the current "block" being executed on the main thread look like? Some "block" needs to finish executing before the main queue can push the next block to the main thread, right?

Comment: This is kind of confusing since your two methods and their code and how they are executed have nothing to do with what thread or queue they are called on and have nothing to do with GCD.

Comment: i agree with rmaddy's comment, and also this code wouldnt get divided up in any way. everything will happen in order in one continuous execution (as far as you are concerned). you would have to actually use a block or something for that to happen, like running an async block on the same queue would let the current execution finish on this thread, then it would get round to your block, then start the runloop again

Comment: I've attempted to edit my question for more clarity. I'm not knowledgeable enough to easily articulate what I'm trying to ask, so hopefully my edits will suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "main thread" is actually running code that looks something like this (heavily simplified):

```
while(1) {
    get command off dispatch queue
    execute command off dispatch queue
}
```

where the "command" is a callback or a block to execute.

Therefore, the main thread divides its work into individual callbacks (like `viewDidLoad`). After each callback executes and completes, the main thread goes to process another command.

Comment: Thanks! So what happens between the main dispatch queue and thread in my example where we call foo from inside viewDidLoad? The message "call viewDidLoad" is pushed off of the dispatch queue, and it's executed by the main thread. 


Does this execution then cause "call foo" to also get pushed onto the queue? The part I'm confused about is how "call viewDidLoad" can finish executing if foo needs to be executed in the middle of viewDidLoad, but "call foo" is on the queue waiting for "call viewDidLoad" to execute.

Comment: I've updated my terminology. The main queue operates in terms of dispatch queue commands; ordinary function executions are not commands. Only dispatch queue commands (e.g. UI callbacks, user-submitted dispatch blocks, etc.) go on the dispatch queue. Everything else is just a normal function execution.

Comment: I see. So the reason deadlock will occur in my example is because "viewDidLoad" is a UI callback, and that callback will never finish completing because it's waiting on dispatch_sync?

And as a followup, does this mean that if we called dispatch_sync on the main queue within a normal function execution, this would not result in deadlock?

I think I'm beginning to understand the source of my confusion: I was not differentiating between UI callbacks and "normal function execution".